# How to write Drools rule to validate several values in an array or list

Tags: java, drools, rule-engine

I have an array with a Collection or an array of values.
I want to write a rule of this form:

```
rule "listRule"

when 
$first: from list1() and $first!= "a" and $first!="b"
$second: from list1() and $second!="c" and $second != "z"
then
System.out.println(" this works!")

end
```

The objective is to be able to evaluate if a list or an array has 2 or more objects($first, $second and so on) that each satisfy a different condition of theirs. It can be an array or list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inserting multiple `String[]` or `List<String>` objects is almost certainly a bad idea because you won't be able to identify these objects. But here's how:

```
rule "listRule"
when
    $list: ArrayList()
    $s1: String( toString != "a" && != "b" ) from $list
    $s2: String( this != $s1, toString !="c" && != "z" ) from $list
then
    System.out.println( "Strings: " + $s1 + " - " + $s2 );
end
```

Comment: worked for me. thanks for the answer. Can I have an or in there? like $s1: String( toString != "a" && != "b" ) from $list  
  or   $s2: String( this != $s1, toString !="c" && != "z" ) from $list

Comment: Yes. Surround both patterns with parentheses. --- But it would not make sense because the same effect could be achieved in a simpler way.

Comment: What do the second and third line in the "when" part do? Do they take the first element from the list, that fits the conditions in the parenthesis after "String"? Or is it a filter function that creates a new list? drools are an undiscoverable nightmare.

Comment: This is simple enough, once you understand that these two pick matching elements (see the constraints) from the list and fire for each matching pair. A long look into the documentation should end your nightmare.